# Numerically evaluating parameter derivatives of a hypergeometric function

Tags: numerics, special-functions

I am unable to obtain the numerical value of the derivative of the hypergeometric function. Please note that the (2,4,0,0) is the derivative with respect to the first and second argument

```
      N[Hypergeometric2F1(2,4,0,0)[0,1,2,1]]
```

Comment: `Derivative[2, 4, 0, 0][ Hypergeometric2F1][0, 1, 2, 1]`

Comment: With `Maple 2020.2` I have: `291.989096054116602579595642923`.

Comment: It is also curious to me that why we can't calculate the 4-order derivative of the second variable. Only 3-order derivative is OK.  `Derivative[2, 3, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][0, 1, 2, 1] // N`

Comment: A dirty workaround: `func = (D[
        D[Pochhammer[a, k] Pochhammer[b, k]/Pochhammer[c, k]*z^k/
          k!, {a, 2}], {b, 4}] // FunctionExpand) /. z -> 1 /. 
    c -> 2 /. b -> 1 // FullSimplify; NSum[
 func /. a -> 10^-12, {k, 0, Infinity}]`

Comment: Another dirty workaround. `((Derivative[2, 3, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][0, 1 + t, 2, 1] - 
    Derivative[2, 3, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][0, 1, 2, 1])/t /. 
   t -> 10^-12) // N`

Answer (score 9):

If I use the [integral representation of the Gaussian hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/01/01/0001/), and then differentiate that before plugging in the arguments, I get the following expression:

$$\frac{2\pi^4}{5}+8 \int_0^1 \left(2(\operatorname{artanh}(1-2t))^2-\pi ^2\right)(\operatorname{artanh}(1-2t)\log(1-t))^2 \, \mathrm dt$$

which does not symbolically evaluate in *Mathematica*, but readily evaluates numerically:

```
(2 π^4)/5 + 8 NIntegrate[(2 ArcTanh[1 - 2 t]^2 - π^2) (ArcTanh[1 - 2 t] Log[1 - t])^2,
                         {t, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
   291.989096054116602579595642919
```

---

In general, [parameter derivatives of hypergeometric functions](https://doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/42/39/395208) can get easily complicated, so I am not overly surprised that a symbolic route did not easily yield a known expression in terms of other special functions known to *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at the [definition of the hypergeometric function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric2F1.html): you can see that $_2F_1(a,b;2;1)=\frac{\Gamma(2-a-b)}{\Gamma(2-a)\Gamma(2-b)}$:

```
h[a_,b_] = Sum[Pochhammer[a, k]*Pochhammer[b, k]/Pochhammer[2, k] * 1/k!, {k, 0, ∞}]
(*    Gamma[2 - a - b]/(Gamma[2 - a] Gamma[2 - b])    *)
```

The general form of this hypergeometric function at $z=1$ is described on the [Wolfram Functions site](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/02/0001/). Thanks @DrWolfgangHintze!

The derivatives now become explicit:

```
D[h[a, b], {a, 2}, {b, 4}] /. {a -> 0, b -> 1} // FullSimplify
(*    68*π^6/315 + 24*(Zeta[3]^2+2*Zeta[5])    *)

% // N
(*    291.989    *)
```

Comment: @ Roman Very good idea! The general formula is $_2F_1(a,b,c,1) = \frac{\Gamma(c-b-a) \Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-b)}$. Unfortunately, my Mathematica was not able to verify this formula.

Comment: @Dr. and Roman, indeed, using [Gauß's hypergeometric theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssHypergeometricTheorem.html) is a clever idea...

Comment: Thanks to Dr. Wolfgang Hintze and J.M. for putting this calculation in its proper mathematical frame.

Answer (score 8):

Increasing `MaxExtraPrecision` to the value `1000` helps.

```
$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000;
N[Derivative[2, 4, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][0, 1, 2, 1],20]
(*291.98909605411660258*)
```

Try this, you will see what is going on:

```
 $MaxExtraPrecision = 100;
 N[Derivative[2, 4, 0, 0][Hypergeometric2F1][0, 1, 2, 1],20]

 (*N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 100.` reached while evaluating (Hypergeometric2F1^(2,4,0,0))[0,1,2,1].*)
 (*292*)
```